# Make C-Extension calls "green" in python

Tags: python, gevent, eventlet, python-extensions, greenlets

I have some python code which is heavily dependent on greenlets.  I can use either `gevent` or `eventlet`.

I have packaged some sections of the code in a C-extension but these calls do not yield to other greenlets.  Is it possible to write my extension such that it will yield control to other python threads while it does not require the GIL?

Answer (score 0):

You can use normal `PyObject_CallFunction(eventlet/greenlet.sleep)` to yield control to other green threads. It must be run with GIL locked, like any other Python code.

You can not run Python code without GIL. (you can but it will quickly go sideways and corrupt memory).

Comment: Thanks for your answer - with this approach how can I control when the greenlet which is in the c-extension is queued again?  Ideally gevent/eventlet would know not to re-queue the greenlet again until it is done with the extension.

Comment: @JMzance Yielding control until future event is called synchronization. There are multiple tools, depending on what you want to synchronize with: event, semaphore, queue, network IO. Show the real code or design problem.